# Como evitar erro quando variavel não esta declarada

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma função que define `onlytest` depois da primeira execução de outro script, porém na primeira execução ele não foi definido..

Como eu posso detectar que ele não foi definido e dar um `return;` para que o coódigo pare? Eu tentei:

```
if(!onlytest) {
return;
}
```

**mas não funciona ele diz que não foi definida, como evitar esse error e dar o return quando ela não estiver definida?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples de verificar se a variável foi definida leva em consideração que o js considera o valor `undefined` como `false` em uma condição. No entanto os valores `null` e `0` também são considerados como `false`.

```
if (onlyteste) {
    // existe
}
```

Uma forma mais correta, tendo em conta que apenas passa quando a variável ainda não foi realmente definida:

```
if (typeof onlyteste != 'undefined') {
    // existe
}
```

Indo ainda um pouco mais longe, o typescript gera o seguinte código:

```
if (onlyteste !== void 0) {
    // existe
}
```

---

**Edit**

Um detalhe na sua pergunta que acabei não percebendo ao elaborar a resposta: caso a variável ainda não esteja **declarada**, apenas a segunda solução que apresentei irá funcionar. Utilize qualquer uma das soluções (com ressalvas a primeira) para verificar se a variável foi inicializada / setada.

```
function minhaFuncao () {
    if (1 == 0) {
        var onlyteste = 'ok';
    }

    if (typeof onlyteste == 'undefined') {
        // variável não existe
    }
}
```

---

```
function minhaFuncao () {
    var onlyteste;
    if (1 == 0) {
        onlyteste = 'ok';
    }

    if (onlyteste) {
        // não inicializada
    }

    if (typeof onlyteste == 'undefined') {
        // não inicializada
    }

    if (onlyteste === void 0) {
        // não inicializada
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o porque do -1, mas continua a dar erro, veja console https://jsfiddle.net/tt7rezse/

Comment: @Elaine Veja que utilizei `typeof onlyteste != 'undefined'` e não `onlyteste != undefined`. A segunda abordagem pode gerar resultados não esperados em casos específicos.

Comment: Funcionou! Grata!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar antes se a variável foi definida.
Assim:

```
if(onlytest !== undefined){
   //Ações aqui
}
```

Dessa forma, você pode saber se a variável foi definida ou não.
E aqui está algo semelhante ao que você queria fazer:

```
if(onlytest === undefined){
   return false;
}
```

Comment: continua a dar erro, veja console https://jsfiddle.net/tt7rezse/